# Find INSTALLDIR of previously installed version

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I am trying to build a major upgrade to our product using InstallShield. It's all working just fine as long as the user didn't choose to install it to a custom location. If they did, none of the code I created to back up and restore the user's settings (.Net config file entries) can be found because the Custom Action is looking in the default location. It doesn't know anything about the location of the original install. The uninstall is able to discover the INSTALLDIR from that installation and uninstall it. FindRelatedProducts shows:

```
FindRelatedProducts: Found application: {E881D894-B624-4B8B-8A02-36E2425E3928}
```

However, I can't find that key anywhere other than under the proprietary registry location, where there is nothing useful:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\InstallShield Uninstall Information\{E881D894-B624-4B8B-8A02-36E2425E3928}
```

The `E881D...` is the ProductCode of the installation I am upgrading. I cannot find the upgrade code anywhere, either in that order or using the MS encoded/packed format.

It seems to me as though being able to find the installation location of the package you are upgrading should be a pretty basic feature since one would expect that when upgrading an application the user likely wants to put it back in the same place. Clearly the information is available somewhere, since ARP and the upgrade installer are able to successfully remove the application.

Also, is there any way to access the values of SecureCustomProperties from the original installation during a major upgrade? I'm pretty sure I know the answer to that...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a component search. Find a component guid for a file that was installed in that INSTALLDIR location (the main application folder, I assume) and use that. In InstallShield I think that's a system search. It will return the path to that component's install location, and it requires the file to be the key path of that component.

For future reference you can prepare for this in at least two ways.

1. If INSTALLDIR is the location, just create a registry item (using the standard IDE) in the location of your choice and give it the value [INSTALLDIR] and this will resolve to the actual location when the item is written to the registry.
2. Another useful tip is to have a type 51 custom action set ARPINSTALLLOCATION to the value [INSTALLDIR] and I'm not sure of thw InstallShield interface for that, but it requires no code. This result in the install location being in the uninstall registry key, but that is basically an implementation detail. The API MsiGetProductInfo (and equivalents) given the ProductCode and INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLLOCATION will return that main application folder location.

Comment: Thanks. I like the ARP solution, even if it is, IMHO, overly convoluted. Being new to installers it never occurred to me that such a basic bit of functionality wouldn't be done automatically by MSI. I don't expect it in IS which is the biggest POS software I've used in 20+ years. And that's having used Lotus Notes.) I'm really regretting not taking the "hit" of learning WiX from the get-go. I will for now of course have to take the component search approach, but I'll fix this installer for the future.

Comment: So I need to partially retract some of my previous comment. It seems that InstallShield _does_ in fact have a custom action type 51 that sets ARPINSTALLLOCATION. I discovered this fact by attempting to add my own named SetARPINSTALLLOCATION, which, coincidentally, happens to be the same name IS chose. Because it's not like they've documented it or anything (go ahead and search for "InstallShield APRINSTALLLOCATION"). Or provided a way to make use of it. Typical half-assed IS implementation.